# Unable to install snowflake-connector-pandas_tools in PyCharm

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pycharm, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to use pd_writer and write_pandas in my code but that requires **snowflake.connector.pandas_tools** package. I am working on the code using PyCharm and unable to find this package in python-interpreter.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install it following our docs:

```
pip install snowflake-connector-python[pandas]
```

More information [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-pandas.html#installation).

Comment: but in PyCharm I don't find such package. Could you please help me with the steps to get this package in PyCharm. Thank you

Comment: PyCharm has an option for Terminal and there you an still use **pip** to install that package.

Comment: Yes, this helped me. Thank you so much